# « Être l’objet de » ou « Être au coeur de »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Johanne (avec deux autres utilisateurs) a été l’objet du premier scandale de l’application Horizon Worlds.

> Johanne (avec deux autres utilisateurs) a été au coeur du premier scandale de l’application Horizon Worlds.

Autre énonciation qui fait surface dans ma tête:

> Johanne (avec deux autres utilisateurs) a fait partie du premier scandale de l’application Horizon Worlds.

Je suis ouvert aux reformulations! Vous pouvez repenser la phrase du tout au tout, pour autant que votre reformulation véhicule la même idée.

Comment: Larousse/*difficultés* peut vous être utile: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/objet/55366#:~:text=%C3%8Atre%20l'objet%20de%20%2F%20faire,fait%20l'objet%20de%20poursuites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première expression (***a été l'objet***), plus rare, indique que Johanne était elle-même l'élément du scandale en question, c'est sa personne qui a fait scandale ou qui l'a subi.

La deuxième expression (***a été au cœur***) indique l'importance de Johanne dans ce scandale mais sous entend qu'elle n'était pas la seule impliquée, que ce scandale n'était pas limité à sa personne, dans l'espace ou dans le temps. Cette forme est plus indiquée ici puisqu'on sait que deux autres personnes étaient concernées.

*Faire partie du premier scandale* me semble moins courant que les expressions précédentes.

Comment: Hormis « être au coeur/centre de », est-ce qu’il existe d’autres expressions permettant de faire passer l’idée en question?

Comment: *S'est retrouvée au cœur*, *au centre*, *a été l'épicentre*, *la première victime*, *la victime principale*, etc. mais *a été au cœur* est très bien.

Comment: "Faire l'objet d'un scandale" est très courant également.

Comment: @Ben Oui. J'ai cependant l'impression que ça implique une responsabilité alors que dans le cas de la question, il s'agit d'une victime.